# I can't get my GUI to display properly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So, I've been making this BankPanel class to go with two other classes my teacher gave us for my Java course. GUI launches, but it isn't displaying any values besides "Unknown" for name and the rest of the text fields are 0's. I'm supposed to change the BankPanel class, not the other classes.

UPDATE: I just need to get the setAcctNumber, setBalance, and setName in BankPanel to acutally change the values to what they need to be.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BankPanel extends JPanel
{
    private int amount;
    private JLabel accountName;
    private JLabel accountNumber;
    private JLabel accountBalance;
    private JLabel accountStatus;
    private JLabel depwitAmount;
    private JTextField accountNameTF;
    private JTextField accountNumberTF;
    private JTextField accountBalanceTF;
    private JTextField accountStatusTF;
    private JTextField depwitAmountTF;
    private JButton depositButton;
    private JButton withdrawButton;
    private int acctNumber;
    private double balance;
    private String name;

    Object myAcct()  // this is where i messed up   
    {
        acctNumber = 128895;
        balance = 0.00;
        name = "Bart Simpson";


    }

    public BankPanel()
   {
      amount = 0;

        accountName = new JLabel ("Account name: ");
        accountNumber = new JLabel ("Account number: ");
        accountBalance = new JLabel ("Account balance: ");
        accountStatus = new JLabel ("Account status: ");
        depwitAmount = new JLabel ("Deposit/Withdraw amount: ");
        accountNameTF = new JTextField (15);
        accountNumberTF = new JTextField (10);
        accountBalanceTF = new JTextField (10);
        accountStatusTF = new JTextField (10);
        depwitAmountTF = new JTextField (10);
        depositButton = new JButton ("Deposit");
        withdrawButton = new JButton ("Withdraw");

        depositButton.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
        withdrawButton.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
        BankPanel obj = new BankPanel(); 

        add (accountName);
        add (accountNameTF);
        add (accountNumber);
        add (accountNumberTF);
        add (accountBalance);
        add (accountBalanceTF);
        add (accountStatus);
        add (accountStatusTF);
        add (depositButton);
        add (withdrawButton);
        add (depwitAmount);
        add (depwitAmountTF);


      setBackground(Color.cyan);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
      accountNameTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      accountNumberTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      accountBalanceTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      accountStatusTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      depwitAmountTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      accountNameTF.setText(myAcct.getName());
      accountNumberTF.setText(Integer.toString ( myAcct.getAcctNumber() ) );
      accountBalanceTF.setText(Double.toString( myAcct.getAcctNumber() ) );

   }
```

This is the BankAccount class:

```
class BankAccount 
{

 private int acctNumber;
 private double balance;
 private String name;

 private static int acctCount= 0;  //not an instance variable, but a class variable (static)

/** constructs a bank account with zero balance, zero account number
 and name set to Unknown

*/

public BankAccount() {
     acctNumber = 0;
     balance = 0.0;
     name = "Unknown";

     acctCount++;
}

/*
  constructs a bank account with an account number, an  initial balance, and
  an owner!
 */

public BankAccount(int acctNo, double initBalance, String owner) {
    acctNumber = acctNo;
    balance = initBalance;
    name = owner;

    acctCount++;
}


 //all of the mutator methods - set

 public void setAcctNumber(int acct)
 {
        acctNumber = acct;
 }

public void setBalance(double amount)
 {
    balance = amount;
 }

 public void setName(String someName)
 {
    name = someName;
 }

//all of the accessor methods - get

public int getAcctNumber()
{
    return acctNumber;
 }

public double getBalance()
 {
 return balance;
}

public String getName()
 {
    return name;
}


public void deposit(double amount)
{
 balance = balance + amount;
}

public void withdraw(double amount) {
 balance = balance - amount;
}

 //overloaded method.  charges a fee!
 public void withdraw(double amount, double fee)
 {
        balance = balance - amount - fee;
 }

public String toString()
{
        return ("BankAccount : acctNumber "  + acctNumber +  " balance : "     + balance 
           + " name : " + name  );
}

//Class method to display our private static variable
public static int getAcctCount()
{
    return ( acctCount );
}

}// end of class definition
```

Main Class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BankGUI
{
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Creates and displays the main program frame.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  JFrame frame = new JFrame ("My Bank Account");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  BankPanel panel = new BankPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: The displayed values are your initial values for your BankAccount Object!? So everything's ok?

Comment: @PrR3 it's supposed to display the name as "Bart Simpson" and then the account number as "128895"

Comment: I think we're not here to solve your homework, but as a hint: use the set-methods to change values of your object!

Comment: @BlakeWinters which is your main class?

Comment: @PrR3 no I know. He didn't provide the BankPanel stuff. I did that with some tips from a friend. and okay

Comment: @javaBeginner It is the 3rd class I was given. All the main class has in it is code that makes GUI open up and Exit on close. I just put it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not setting any values thats why `Bart Simpson` is not displayed
set the values like this

```
BankAccount b=new BankAccount();
b.setName("Bart Simpson");
b.setBalance(0.00);
b.setAcctNumber(128895);
```

Comment: When i change them to "set________", it just says it doesnt have a field/cannot be resolved

Comment: @BlakeWinters post the stacktrace

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 setAcctNumber cannot be resolved or is not a field
 setBalance cannot be resolved or is not a field
 setname cannot be resolved or is not a field

 at bankAccountGUI.BankPanel.<init>(BankPanel.java:40)
 at bankAccountGUI.BankGUI.main(BankGUI.java:22)

Comment: I just did. I just can't figure out why setAcctNumber, setBalance, and setName aren't actually changing the values

Comment: @BlakeWinters where have written BankAccount b=new BankAccount();
b.setName("Bart Simpson");
b.setBalance(0.00);
b.setAcctNumber(128895);

Comment: I just figured it out. I was using the mutator methods wrong. i had myAcct.setAcctNumber = 128895; when it needed to be myAccts.setAcctNumber (128895);

Comment: i used myAcct instead of b